# Error ':app:compileDebugKotlin' java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException after migrating to Androidx

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, kapt

After I migrate my project there some error like data binding and more, but I already solve it then the error change into this :

```
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

I've try many solution like updating kotlin version to 1.4.20 and also some source ask me to upgrade the room version so I update it to the latest version but it all turns out failed.

here is my gradle module :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'

android {

compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "my package"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.18"
    testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility 1.8
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
}

buildFeatures {
    dataBinding = true
}

}

 dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.3.2'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.3'
kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.3'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

implementation 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.1.1'
implementation 'jp.wasabeef:fresco-processors:2.1.0'

implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.72"
implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.github.IntruderShanky:Sectioned-RecyclerView:2.1.1'
implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'


implementation 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.2.0'

kapt 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.2.0'
def room_version = "2.2.6"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"

implementation files('libs/jxl.jar')
implementation 'com.github.myinnos:AlphabetIndex-Fast-Scroll-RecyclerView:1.0.8'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'

implementation 'com.github.Kunzisoft:Android-SwitchDateTimePicker:1.9'
implementation "com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.3"
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
implementation 'com.github.AnyChart:AnyChart-Android:0.0.3'
implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.itextpdf:itext7-core:7.1.7'
implementation 'com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.4'
implementation files('libs/google-api-translate-java-0.98-mod2.jar')
implementation files('libs/json_simple-1.1.jar')
implementation files('libs/jtar-1.0.4.jar')
implementation files('libs/microsoft-translator-java-api-0.6-mod.jar')
implementation 'com.stepstone.stepper:material-stepper:4.3.1'
implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
implementation 'com.kyanogen.signatureview:signature-view:1.0'
implementation("com.microblink:blinkid:5.9.0@aar") {
    transitive = true
}
implementation 'com.itextpdf:itext7-core:7.1.7'
implementation deps.kotlin
implementation deps.android.support.appcompat
implementation deps.android.support.constraintlayout
implementation 'com.github.yeriomin:play-store-api:0.19'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.9.0'//for new version updater
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.github.jakebonk:NotifyMe:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.szagurskii:patternedtextwatcher:0.5.0'
implementation 'com.schibstedspain.android:leku:5.0.0'
testImplementation deps.test.junit
androidTestImplementation deps.test.runner
androidTestImplementation deps.test.espresso

}
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy {
    force("org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:4.5.3")
    force("org.antlr:antlr4-tool:4.5.3")
}
}
```

and this is my gradle project :

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.72"
    classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:10.2.3'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
 }

 allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.microblink.com' }

}
}

ext {
  supportlib_version = '27.1.1'
  appcompat_version = supportlib_version
  design_version = supportlib_version
  constraintlayout_version = '1.1.0'
  junit_version = '4.12'
  testrunner_version = '1.0.2'
  espresso_version = '3.0.2'
}

 ext.deps = [
    'kotlin' : "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.72",
    'android': [
            'support': [
                    'core'            : "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportlib_version",
                    'appcompat'       : 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0',
                    'constraintlayout': 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3',
                    'design'          : "com.android.support:design:$design_version"
            ]
    ],
    'test'   : [
            'junit'   : "junit:junit:$junit_version",
            'runner'  : 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1',
            'espresso': 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    ]
  ]

 task clean(type: Delete) {
 delete rootProject.buildDir
 }

 project.ext {
    blinkIdVersion = '5.9.0'
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'
    appCompatVersion = '28.0.0'
 }
```

Comment: as I remember I had similar error and I fixed it with removing `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` from `build.gradle`

Comment: I just try your solution by removing it and change the kapt into annotationprocessor but the error become unresolverd BR, when I search it mush use kapt because of the version of android studio  @Andrew

Answer (score 1):

1. Please do not remove `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` from the gradle file. As it is required for annotation processor.
2. Please check all the Room queries in your DAO file for syntax error. The error mentioned in your question mostly occurs when the Room Database Queries are incorrect.
3. Please refer to below image to get more clear **error log**. These steps will take you closer to the exact error.
   [image]
4. Lastly,  try running build with --stacktrace OR --info OR --debug option to get more clear log output and full insights. This way you will be able to find solution for error.